# Find original IDT entries

Tags: windows, kernel, interrupt

I'm just learning the basics of Windows kernel and I have just run into a problem. I want to check if any entries of IDT are hooked. As I see, for example XueTr (PcHunter) can tell me the original value of a specific IDT entry (and so if it is hooked), but I don't know how can I find the original values of this table? For example in SSDT the original values can be extracted from the ntoskrnl image, but IDT is not Windows specific.

Thx!

Comment: You answer your question, compare IDT from disk to the IDT on memory.

Comment: The problem is that I do not exactly know where I can find "IDT from disk".

Comment: Nobody knows from where the IDT is filled during windows startup? :S

Comment: The problem is that I do not exactly know where I can find "IDT from disk - in ntoskrnl.exe, in the INIT section.